# Properties of $\sigma$-Algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. If there existis $\{B_i \, \vert\; i \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathcal{A}$, such that $B_i \neq B_j$ for $i \neq j$ (2-by-2 distinct). Show that;

$i$) There exists $\{D_k \, \vert \; k \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset\mathcal{A}$, such that $D_k \cap D_q = \emptyset$  for $k \neq q$ (2-by-2 disjoint).

$ii$) $\mathcal{A} \gtrapprox 2^{\mathbb{N}}$. That is, there exists an injection from $\mathcal{A}$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}} \thickapprox \mathbb{R}$.  $\;\;\;\;$ $\left(\mbox{Hint: Use the results of } i\right)$

Comment: The injection should go the other way around: $2^{\Bbb N}\to \mathcal A$.

Comment: @Berci, this is how the question was passed. Can you elaborate on this injection $2^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: The injection as described by @Berci is the *definition* of the inequality at the beginning of your statement ii).  The injection that you wrote in ii) would be the definition of the reverse inequality.

Comment: Also, statement i) should require the sets $D_k$ to be nonempty. Otherwise, you could solve i) by taking all $D_k=\varnothing$ and that wouldn't help at all with ii).

Comment: @Andreas Blass, I still don't see it, could you elaborate on the inequality? All $D_k$ being non empty is assumed.

Comment: @Nikolawn I can't think of more to say about the inequality. Just look up the definition of inequality between cardinal numbers and apply it to your specific inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the following:

$i)$ Consider the collection $\left\{D_i \,\vert\; i \in \{k, \cdots, n\} \right\}$ such that $D_k = A_k$, $D_{k+1} = A_{k+1}\setminus(A_{k+1} \cap A_k)$, $D_{k+2} = A_{k+2} \setminus(A_{k+2} \cap A_{k+1} \cap A_k)$, $\;\;\cdots\;$, $D_n = A_n \setminus \left(\bigcap_{i = k}^{n} A_i\right)$, we have that this finite collection is indeed disjoint. Since $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ are arbitrary, the above then holds for any $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ of consecutive natural numbers. It follows that $\left\{D_i \, \vert \; i \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a disjoint collection of elements.

Note that, $D_1 \in \mathcal{A}$. Let $x \in D_k = A_k \setminus(\bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i)$, then $x \in A_k$ and $x \notin \bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i$, it follows that $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^k A_{i}^{c}$ ($A_i^c$ is the complement of $A_i$). However, $A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$ (since $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$), then $\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$. Therefore $D_k \in \mathcal{A}$ for $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{D_i \in \mathcal{A}\, \vert \; i \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathcal{A}$.